# Compare and replace lists in function of their lenghts

Tags: python

I have Two lists, let's say A & B :
(A is the reference name and B is the new name)

What I want is :
if A is bigger than B (len(A)=5 ; len(B) = 3) :the 3 elements B replace the 3 (=>len(B)) firsts elements of A (and print a warning message)

if B is bigger than A (len(A)=5 ; len(B) = 6) : the 5 firsts elements of B replace the 5 (=>len(A)) firsts elements of A (and print a different warning message)

if A= B then B replace A

I have a solution but I want to know if it is the fastest or the smartest way of doing it and if some functions do this kind of replacement automatically ?

```
A = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

if len(A)>len(B) :
    A[:len(B)] = B
    print("warning message")
if len(B)>len(A) : 
    A[:len(A)] = B[:len(A)]
    print("different warning message")

if len(A) == len(B) :
    A=B
```

Edit: correction of errors

Comment: = is the assignment operator. == is the comparison operator. You are comparing lengths, so you need to use the comparison operator

Comment: Using elif instead of regular if will save some unnecessary evaluations. In your last condition, you are making A point to the list B, any modification to the list B will affect list A. Not sure if this is really what you want, since in the other two cases you are not doing this.

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing built-in that will do this.

Comment: Your first two conditions do the replacement in place. But the assignment `A=B` doesn't work in place. Why this inconsistency?

Comment: `A[:len(A)]` can be simplified to just `A[:]`

Comment: What do you mean by saving some evaluations ? sorry I am a beginner @Sembei Norimaki

Comment: What do you mean by In place ? I don't understand @Barmar

Comment: Assigning to a slice replaces elements of the original list.

Comment: If the first condition evaluates true because A is longer than B, then you don't need to evaluate if B is longer or equal than A. Use an elif instead of an if.

Comment: but what about if they are equal ? @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation about if elif to understand the differences between putting if elifs and parallel ifs. If the lengths are equal you will evaluate the three conditions, no difference in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do a slicing based on the minimum length of the two lists:

```
A[:min(len(A),len(B))] = B[:min(len(A),len(B))]
```

`A=[1,2,3,4] and  B=['a','b','c'] => A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 4]`

`A=[1,2,3,4] and  B=['a','b','c','d','e','f'] => A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

`A=[1,2,3,4] and  B=['a','b','c','d'] => A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I wanted to do ! Thank you I knew there was a way of making it simpler I just could not wrap my head around it

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems fine, but using `if/elif/else` would be better than three `if` statements.  There is no built-in function I'm aware of to do this particular kind of swapping.

If I'm understanding the swap you want correctly, this can all be done in two lines of code:

```
print("warning message" if len(A)>len(B)
      else "different warning message" if len(B)>len(A)
      else "")
A = B[:len(A)] + A[len(B):]
```

Here is an alternative solution using itertools.zip_longest(), and converting this all into a function.  I wrote this first before realizing the simpler solution for the warning message.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def replace_a_with_b(A: list, B: list) -> list:
    result = []
    warn = False
    for a, b in zip_longest(A, B):
        if a and b:
            result.append(b)
        elif a:
            result.append(a)
            if not warn:
                print("warning message")
                warn = True
        elif b:
            print("different warning message")
            break
    return result

A = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
A = replace_a_with_b(A, B)
print(A)
```